# how to expect if item is present in the list

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

How can I compare a String with a List of `ng-repeat`:

```
this.TenantList = element.all(by.repeater("tenant in tenantList"));

TenantList.getAttribute('aria-label').then(function(list) {
    //label contains 10 items and I want to see if this list contains 'Test'
    expect(list).toMatch('Test');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually make the expectation in one go with `toContain()` matcher:

```
expect(TenantList.getAttribute('aria-label')).toContain('Test');
```

---

Note that there is no need to resolve the promise with `then()` - `expect()` is capable of understanding if there is a promise passed in and resolving it under-the-hood.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe it helped.